# Kotlin enum with multiple "parameter"

Tags: kotlin, enums

For an exercise I have an enum (set by the teacher) that looks like this :

```
enum class Weapon(name: String, damage: Int) {
    SWORD("Sword", 12),
    AXE("Axe", 13),
    BOW("Bow", 14)
}
```

The weapon will be an attribute of a `data class Player`
But once I set `player.weapon = Weapon.SWORD`
How do i access to the `name` or `damage` of the `weapon` ?

I have looked on the Internet for an answer but didn't find anywhere an enum with two "parameter" (don't know how to call it) so I start wondering if this enum is possible.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#initialization), you need to declare the `name` and `damage` as properties of the enum class, using the `val` keyword:

```
enum class Weapon(val weaponName: String, val damage: Int)
```

Then you'll be able to simply access `player.weapon.weaponName`.

Comment: Oh yeah and I can't call it `name`, as there already a `name` member in Enum.

Thank you for your quick answer.